# How should I filter columns in RECORD without breaking nest?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I use BigQuery to receive analytics data from Firebase, and now I'd like to filter some columns.

Here's a data scheme (simplified).

```
device                           RECORD   NULLABLE
  device.category                STRING   NULLABLE
  device.vendor_id               STRING   NULLABLE
  device.is_limited_ad_tracking  STRING   NULLABLE
```

I don't need `vendor_id` column, but I'd like to preserve `device` nest like this:

```
device                           RECORD   NULLABLE
  device.category                STRING   NULLABLE
  device.is_limited_ad_tracking  STRING   NULLABLE
```

At first I wrote `` SELECT device.category, device.is_limited_ad_tracking FROM `my_table` ``, but `category` and `is_limited_ad_tracking` column become unnested.

```
  category                STRING   NULLABLE
  is_limited_ad_tracking  STRING   NULLABLE
```

How can I filter columns without breaking nest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRUCT(device.category, device.is_limited_ad_tracking) device
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can smoke test it with below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT STRUCT<category STRING, vendor_id STRING, is_limited_ad_tracking STRING>('c1', 'id1', 'is1') device
)
SELECT STRUCT(device.category, device.is_limited_ad_tracking) device
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thanks. I got what I needed!